# window popstate event not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, browser-history

I have tried to disable browser back button by this code :

```
<script>
    //disable back button
    history.pushState(null, null, ' '); 
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, ' ');
    });
</script>
```

It works in **Chrome**, **Mozila**, **IE10**, but does not work for safari(5.x).

Has anyone achieved this before crossbrowser ?

Comment: I have further looked that pushSate is supported in Safari , but the popstate event is not firing

Comment: It worked for latest Safari.

Comment: Please try it with my code and let me know the status.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
history.pushState(null, null, Url);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    history.pushState(null, null, Url);
});
```

this work fine but I also have another solution for safari browser:

```
history.replaceState(null, null, 'url');
history.pushState(null, null, 'url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code below,

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
```

This code is working fine on safari 5.1.7.
You can test with this code and let me know the status.